# Is it wise to put all of the data to blockchain network?

Tags: blockchain, nft, markets, performance

I am building the NFT Marketplace based on ethereum blockchain, and i discovered the smart contract could replace the database for storing all of the transactions and all of the user's property, but i am thinking about the performance and the consideration about storing the data, is it wise to put all of the data to the ethereum blockchain?
lets consider that one page needs to display the paging NFT data , ten per ten, and each call will trigger the smart contract, lets say the function `getUserNFt(page,limit,user)`
since the function doesnt take any ethereum stored in the wallet, i can use this for displaying the page. but is it wise to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all depends on the use case.

Storing data on the chain and iterating over it, e.g. for search purpose, cost gas which is limited resource and on public chain costs real money. Therefore, the cost of such operations might doesn't fit your business model.

A transaction which writes data on the chain have to be executed and later approved by the rest of nodes on the chain. It takes time (hours, days) and what is more important it could be rejected in the process, so you have to repeat again. It is another restriction for your use case.

You could deploy a project on the private chain. It will solve some issues described above, but it has its own limits too.

Personally for my project I put on chain only the most important parts of my project as signed agreements and deploy it with self hosted a private network. To learn more about this [here is a publication](https://gelassen.github.io/blog/2023/04/02/swap-tech-notes-part-1.html).